# Domino Designer V10 Performance Issue

Tags: domino-designer-eclipse

Recently I upgraded to Designer Release 10.0.1FP2  from Designer 9.0.1FP10 with IF6.  Performance has dropped considerably.  When I open an xsp design element (XPages or Custom Controls) it takes 7+ seconds to allow me to start developing.  When I save a design element it takes 15 plus seconds to save it.  This also happens with managed beans.  Sometimes the designer just locks up and and Lotus completely crashes.  When I close out a design element (no saving needs to be done) it takes 5+ seconds to close each design element.  I have searched and searched and found no answers or suggestions on this issue I am having.  Any ideas??

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions from Nathan's post: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjio_6v5PjiAhVLh1wKHWePD8IQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnathantfreeman.files.wordpress.com%2F2013%2F04%2Ftamingdesigner.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Q6YfGFqgONR1GKf4I0cph

Comment: Thanks - That is exactly what I was looking for - I knew it existed somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same thing: I needed to exclude Notes + Notes\Data directories from Windows Defender to get the performance back. Try to do that in your security solution on your pc: might work for you to...

Comment: We have Windows Defender de-activated so unfortunately that's not the issue.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Rob Mason's suggestion above did the trick.  I needed to tweak Domino Designer and the article linked above helped me tweak it.  Thank you Rob for the suggestion and Nathan for creating the document.

Comment: Pleased that worked for you, Mike.

You can do yourself a really big favour by backing up your settings:  Open the `Package Explorer` view, right-click the white space and choose `Export`.  Type `Preferences` and then export all of them to a file for future restoration.